# find combinations of array where some elements should not change the order

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, combinations, permutation

I am new to programming, I need all possible combinations of arrays where order of array1 should not change, and all elements in the array1 should present in the combination.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

array2 = [a, b, c, d]
```

where order of the array1(1 2 3 4 5) should not change and no repetition, only we need to change the positions of array2(a b c d).

```
valid outputs:
[1, a, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, b, a, 2, 3, d, 4, 5]

invalid outputs:

[1, b, 3, 5, 4, a, 2]
```

Comment: what does not work? please add **your** code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: please add your attempt (code or pseudocode) at solving that problem